# Why isn't this a contradiction?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Consider the function $f: \Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = \log(x)$. Then $f$ is continuous. The domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R^+$ and the range of $f$ is $\Bbb R$.

We have the following fact: (proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437829/the-preimage-of-continuous-function-on-a-closed-set-is-closed))

> A function $g : X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if for every closed $W \subseteq Y$, its preimage $g^{-1}(W) \subseteq X$ is closed.

But $f$ is continuous, $\Bbb R$ is closed and its preimage $\Bbb R^+ = (0, +\infty)$ is open. This seems to be a contradiction. I assume I'm missing something obvious...what's going on here?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^+$ is closed inside itself-

Comment: @mathma Sorry, I don't see why that is? The sequence $a_n = 1/n$ converges to $0$, and $a_n \in \Bbb R^+$ but $0 \not\in \Bbb R^+$.

Comment: @aras Like you said $0 \not\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, so $a_n \to 0$ doesn't make sense. If you were asking whether $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ was closed inside $\mathbb{R}$ then your sequence would make sense as $1/n \to 0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Isn't the set of real numbers both open and closed? Perhaps that would affect the validity of applying the rule.

Comment: In short, $a_n=\frac1n$ is not a convergent sequence in $\mathbb R^+$. (This shows that $\mathbb R^+$ is not a complete metric space.)

Comment: You need to consider the relative topology when using that theorem. Closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^+$ are of the shape $F\cap\mathbb{R}^+$, where $F$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. For instance (0,1] would be closed there but not in $\mathbb{R}$. And in particular $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is closed.

Comment: @mathma That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: The open ends are not actually achievable by the function as the input values to achieve are not in the domain.  The domain of valid arguments is open so the domain of valid outputs is (at least) half open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain $\mathbb{R}^+$ needs to be considered as its own topological space and **not** as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

If you do this, then $\mathbb{R}^+$ is closed because any sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^+$  *that converges*, does so to a point of $\mathbb{R}^+$.