# How to prove for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $\{x \in F \colon f(x) \leq r\}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $F$ be a closed real set and let $f$ be a continuous function $f \colon F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

How can I prove that, for all real number $r$, the set $D = \{x \in F \colon f(x) \leq r\}$ is a closed set?

Thank you.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437829/the-preimage-of-continuous-function-on-a-closed-set-is-closed)

Comment: The set $(\infty, r]$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (at least under the usual Euclidean topology).

Comment: We know that $(\infty, r]$ and $D$ are both closed set. The problem here is how can I prove that $D$ is closed? Could you give me an insight on how can I link $(\infty, r]$ to $D$?  But I don't think it does suffice, since $D$ may be empty as I recall.

Comment: Do you know that if $f : X \to Y$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$ for each closed $C \subset  Y$?

Comment: @nhmwhhxx.  Wake up, that set is empty.

Comment: I did in fact just wake up... good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are essentially supposed to be proving one direction of the equivalence between the metric and topological concepts of "closed", rather than just using the latter:

We wish to show that $\mathbb{R}\setminus D$ is open. That is, given any $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus D$, we wish to show that there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $(x - \delta, x + \delta) \cap D = \emptyset$.

So, suppose not. Then there is some $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus D$ such that for any $\delta > 0$, there is some $y_\delta \in (x - \delta, x + \delta) \cap D$. In particular, for every natural $n$, there is some $y_n \in (x - \frac{1}{n}, x + \frac{1}{n})\cap D$.

Now, $|y_n - x| < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$, so $(y_n) \to x$.

Since $f$ is continuous, then, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(y_n) = f\left(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}y_n\right) = f(x)$.

But also, $y_n \in D$ for all $n$, so $f(y_n) \leq r$ for all $n$. Thus, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(y_n) \leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}r = r$.

Combining these gives $f(x) \leq r$, so $x \in D$, a contradiction.

Thus, we conclude that indeed, $\mathbb{R}\setminus D$ is open, and hence $D$ is closed.