# If $g$ is continuous and $A$ is a closed set and $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, then $g^{-1}(A)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Definition: Let $g$ be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. If $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, define
> $$g^{-1}(A)=\{ x\in\mathbb{R}:~ g(x)\in A\}$$

True or false:

If $g$ is continuous and $A$ is a closed set and $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, then $g^{-1}(A)$ is closed.

This problem is found from Understanding Analysis (Ex.4.4.12(d), by Abbott, Stephen). I found the answer from internet showing this statement is True. But can I use the following counter-example?

$$\begin{align} g(x)&=3x-1,~x\in[1/3,~2/3]\\
\\
g(x)&=1, ~~~~~~~~~~x\in (2/3,1)\\
\\
g(x)&=0,~~~~~~~~~~x\in(0,1/3)
\end{align}$$

So $A=[0,1]$ is closed. But $g^{-1}(A)=(0,1)$ is not closed.

Comment: What is $g(x)$ for $x \notin (0,1)$?

Comment: On a semi-related tangent: Official Norwegian high school teaching guidelines say that with functions that have bounded, closed domains, the endpoints can't be local extrema, because the function isn't defined on any open subset around the end point. I will rant about this at any possible opportunity.

Comment: On a side note, this is one of several equivalent definitions of continuity

Comment: I see, thank you for mentioning this! @azif00

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437829/721644).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $g$ that you have described is not defined on all of $\Bbb R$. It is, in fact, only defined on $(0, 1)$. So this "counterexample" is not a counterexample to the given claim, because $g$ doesn't have the right form.

Here is the kicker, though: If we restrict ourselves to only looking at the domain of $g$, then the subset $g^{-1}(A) = (0, 1)$ (which happens to be all of the domain of $g$) then it is indeed closed.

Note that closedness is a property that subsets have in relation to an ambient space, not a property that a set has all by itself. And in relation to the ambient space $(0, 1)$, the subset $(0, 1)$ is closed. In relation to the ambient space $\Bbb R$, the subset $(0, 1)$ is not closed, but that's not relevant to our $g$.

So the theorem you qoute *does* hold in even more general circumstances, assuming you use the correct definition of "closed". But I suspect that a deepdive into relative topologies is not one of the immediate priorities of your math education. So for the moment, just make sure your functions have all of $\Bbb R$ as domain when you apply this result.

Comment: (To all the pedants out there: I am using the standard topologies everywhere.)

Comment: Ah, I got your meaning, so $(0,1)$ with respect to $(0,1)$ is like $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to $\mathbb{R}$, both of them are both open and closed.

Comment: @MathFail Exactly. And with respect to $(0,1)$, the interval $(0,\frac12]$ is also closed, and so on. There is theory to back this up (I realize the "and so on" can be mysterious to someone not familiar with this theory), but it's a bit much for a comment. Relative topology and subspace topology are synonymous, relevant terms, should you decide to search for further information yourself (topology is the study of open and closed sets and continuous functions).

Comment: Yes, thank you for the example, I can make an analogy $(0, 1/2]$ with respect to $(0,1)$ is like $(-\infty, 1/2]$ with respect to $\mathbb{R}$, both the two cases are closed with respect to their ambient spaces.